# Allow edit resource on manyToMany relations - dropdown is disabled

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a manyToMany relations on a Company resource, that subscribes to a subscription plan.
On all companies where a plan is attached, I can click on the Edit icon and thats great. But I cannot open the dropdown and change the selected option, because the dropdown is disabled. Is i t not possible to change this?
[image: Edit selection in belongsToMany]

```
BelongsToMany::make(__('Subscription plan'), 'plans', Plan::class),
```

Comment: Check whether you have policy for your resource model

Comment: Nova has a policy for all resource models, but do you mean if I have created my own Policy for this? Is there something specific you are referring to, that I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
BelongsToMany::make(__('Subscription plan'), 'plans', Plan::class)
             ->searchable(), // <-- add this option here
```

Here are the [docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/relationships.html#searchable-relations) regarding this.

Comment: Thanks @techouse, but it doesn't appear to make any difference. As far as I understand, then adding ->searchable() will only add a search function in the dropdown. But the dropdown is still disabled.